# Mutual exclusive pair of natural numbers

Tags: coq

I have a function that gives me pair of natural numbers.
Each pair is identified by its serial number, like `sr1=(1,25)` `sr2=(26,50)` `sr3=(51,75)`.
Average of numbers is 25. Then I have another function that gives me list of natural number that exist between the first and the second of each pair, like `l1=[1,2,......25]` `l2=[26,27...50]`.

I want to prove that if serial numbers of pairs are different, then no element is repeated in the list. Hence pairs are mutual exclusive.

```
Lemma lgroups: forall sn1 sn2 avg, 
S sn1 < S sn2 -> 
avg =? 0  = false ->
(S sn1 * avg <? S sn2 * avg - (avg - 1) = true)

Proof. intros. induction sn1 .  rewrite mult_1_l.
simpl. induction sn2. simpl. rewrite plus1_0_r.
destruct avg. inversion H0. inversion H .
```

Comment: Could you please try to explain your problem better? Maybe show us how you tried to prove the lemma. Also having the actual definitions could help identify what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: sn1 is the serial no as sr1 ,assign to first pair sn1=(1,25) sn2 is the serial no assign to second pair sn2=(26,50). sn1 is less than sn2  and natural numbers from 1 to 25 are less than natural numbers from 26 to 50. Average is 25. Therefore  every serial no that comes before the other,should less.like sn1<sn2,,sn3<sn4.

Comment: A little bit of formatting. Probably not enough to make it more undertandable though.

Comment: Simply I have divided the natural numbers which are in sequence, in group of 25 .Each group is identified by its sn(serial  no),like sn1=(1,25),sn2=(26,50).Avg is 25. Sn1<Sn2,then (1,25)< (26,50).To check this ,I am trying to prove that snd(p1)<fst(p2) for every group.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to answer your question with what I could understand from it. Really, I think you should take time to format your questions better, especially if you want (quick) answers! You also seem to be a beginner in Coq, you should probably have a look at some tutorials (see [this page](https://coq.inria.fr/documentation), "Software Foundations" is one of the most used).

Answer (score 2):

The context is not completely clear to me, but I can answer the problem of proving the given lemma.

Firstly, such lemma would typically not be stated using the boolean operations, but using their propositional counterparts. This would give something like this.

```
Lemma lgroups: forall sn1 sn2 avg,
  S sn1 < S sn2 -> 
  avg <> 0 ->
  S sn1 * avg < S sn2 * avg - (avg - 1).
```

Secondly, I would also favour the use of `+` instead of `-` in general when manipulating natural numbers, since the behaviour of the latter is a bit unnatural due to the absence of negative numbers. I think, in your case, this also makes more sense, since it correctly expresses the intuitive statement "the last element of the current sequence is less than the first occurrences of the following ones", while I am a bit unclear about the meaning of your original statement.

```
Lemma lgroups: forall sn1 sn2 avg,
  S sn1 < S sn2 -> 
  avg <> 0 ->
  S sn1 * avg + avg - 1 < S sn2 * avg.
```

Thirdly, I would also drop the `S` everywhere, since the result also holds in this case and is strictly stronger.

```
Lemma lgroups: forall sn1 sn2 avg,
  sn1 < sn2 -> 
  avg <> 0 ->
  sn1 * avg + avg - 1 < sn2 * avg.
```

For the proof, such simple arithmetic proofs can actually be proved automatically by certain tactics, in particular the tactic `nia` from [Micromega](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/micromega.html).

This finally gives:

```
Require Import Lia.

Lemma lgroups: forall sn1 sn2 avg,
  sn1 < sn2 -> 
  avg <> 0 ->
  sn1 * avg + avg - 1 < sn2 * avg.
Proof.
  intros. nia.
Qed.
```

Comment: Can u solve my another problem?I have some natural numbers(like 500).I divide them into different groups(20).Each group is identified by ser# 1,2...20.Elements in each group will be 25. Total natural number (500) which we are going to divide into group of 25 elements,must be greater than total number of groups

`Lemma totnum_nogrp: forall totnum nogrp,

nogrp <=? totnum = true -> (totnum / nofgrp =? 0) = false.`